# change the source image of boot disk GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I want to change the source image of boot disk which is attached to one of running VM instance. Boot disk and VM are created using terraform. Is there anyway we can detach the boot disk and attach a new one ? or is there any new other ways to do this ? or is there any way we can achieve this using Terraform ? please assist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to change the source image of boot disk which is attached to
> one of running VM instance.

You cannot change the source image once the VM instance is created. The source image is used to layout the boot disk and install the operating system. The source image is no longer used once the boot disk is created.

> Is there anyway we can detach the boot disk and attach a new one ?

Yes, you can detach a boot disk and replace it with another boot disk.

This command will detach a boot disk for a **stopped** VM instance:

```
gcloud compute instances detach-disk NAME --disk=DISK --zone=ZONE
```

This command will attach a boot disk:

```
gcloud beta compute instances attach-disk NAME --disk=DISK --zone=ZONE --boot
```

> is there any way we can achieve this using Terraform?

I am not aware of Terraform HCL that will detach and attach boot disks to already created instances.

Comment: thanks @John Hanley . once i attach the disk back to the VM and start the instance , Im not able to see cassandra , kafka process running ... do we need to manually restart ?

Comment: @Abyy Create a new question about Cassandra or Kafka with details.